# Display Icon from ListView Item into PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, icons

How would I be able to take a listView containing icons and text, and then display the listView icon chosen in a pictureBox? The code has a button load in the processes and their icons in the listView.

The listView looks like this:

[image: Icons]

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int intselectedindex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
    if (intselectedindex >= 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listView1.Items[intselectedindex].Text;
        //pictureBox1.Image = ???
    }
}
private void bunifuThinButton21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = "SELECT ProcessId, Name, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process";
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    using (var results = searcher.Get())

    {
        var processes = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(x => new
        {
            ProcessId = (UInt32)x["ProcessId"],
            Name = (string)x["Name"],
            ExecutablePath = (string)x["ExecutablePath"]
        });
        foreach (var p in processes)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(p.ExecutablePath))
            {
                listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
                var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.ExecutablePath);
                var key = p.ProcessId.ToString();
                this.imageList1.Images.Add(key, icon.ToBitmap());
                this.listView1.Items.Add(p.Name, key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using image key to assign images to items, you can get the image of selected item this way:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
{
    var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    if (item.ImageList != null)
        pictureBox1.Image = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageKey];
}
```